# Can I sell a Craigslist/FB Marketplace item in a local store?

Tags: united-states, business, liability, property

I want to sell a high value cell phone but I also want to stay safe.

Are there any issues with me choosing a local grocery store or restaurant to conduct the transaction (goods for money)? Does it matter if it is in the parking lot vs inside? Should I choose a shopping mall instead so that I am not physically inside a store?

I know this is kind of vague but I was just wondering if the store could pursue legal action against me or anything if they notice the activity.

NY, USA

Comment: Legal action for what?

Comment: @Putvi I'm not sure. You're asking me my own question. If you need a re-phrasal then: Would they have an issue with me performing a transaction on their property without their consent?

Comment: I don't think anyone cares if you exchange something you sold on Facebook.

Comment: @Putvi Thank you for the opinion but I am trying to see if there is any legal reason for me to not perform a transaction at a business location.

Comment: Theres not some law about selling Facebook stuff at a local business. I don't mean this in a mean way, but I doubt the business would know you were there.

Comment: @Putvi Once again, thank you for the opinion but it fails miserably to answer my question.

Comment: It doesn't fail lol. I've told you to do it if you want and don't if you want. Where you hand off a Facebook marketplace item has no relation to the law to be honest.

Comment: I wish you luck in selling your stuff, but there just aren't specific laws about handing off stuff you sold on Facebook.

Comment: Did someone tell you there are laws about it? What makes you concerned? @MonkeyZeus

Comment: @Putvi This requires a bit of imagination but here goes nothing: If I am selling something for $400 and the transaction (money and goods) takes place at a store then could the store claim ownership of the proceeds since their ToS states that any transactions are property of the store? If the deal goes awry due to negotiations and the buyer trashes an aisle out of rage then am I liable for damages for inciting the situation? stuff like that...

Comment: I mean if you signed an agreement with the store saying any business done there then yes it would be the store's property, but I don't know of any stores that do that. No, you aren't liable for damages. Why would you be? Again, I don't mean it in a mean way or to say I am not listening to your question, but people exchange stuff they bought online in stores or other public places everyday. I really don't think anyone would even notice you did it.

Comment: I have zero doubt that I would go unnoticed and that is 100% expected/desired. I was hoping to hear about imaginative ways that it could affect me rather than being told what I already know in that it probably isn't an issue.

Comment: I think I get you now, but honestly the worst they can do is ask you to leave. If I said anything else, I would be making it up.

Comment: @Putvi Sorry for the brevity of my initial question but I did not want answers focusing on a specific situation like I provided. It's possible that my question is a little too broad but I was just hoping to hear whether or not stores are able to pursue me in general; aside from simply asking me to leave.

Comment: No, they can't do anything other than asking you to leave. The same rules apply to people in a store whether you are selling Facebook stuff or not. If a store could do other things to you they wouldn't need you to be selling Facebook stuff to do it.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any issues with me choosing a local grocery store or
>   restaurant to conduct the transaction?

Yes. Strictly speaking, the interesting scenario you outline in the latter portion of [this comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38712/can-i-sell-a-craigslist-fb-marketplace-item-in-a-local-store#comment70469_38712) might render both parties liable to the store owner and/or others present (collectively, "the store") even if only one party causes harm. I will focus on this scenario. As for the store claiming ownership of the proceeds, I deem it unlikely to succeed.

Regardless of whether or not the transaction (and subsequent disturbance) can be considered a form of *loitering*, the store could prevail under *principles of equity* and hold both parties *jointly and severally liable*. That is because both parties deliberately arranged to utilize the store for an external transaction without the store's permission and which does not benefit the store.

Furthermore, the evident failure to notify the store in advance about the parties' plans implies that the store was deprived of the opportunity to assess the need for special arrangements, such as (1) ensuring that security personnel supervises the store during the meetup, or (2) conditioning that the transaction be performed at a more convenient time (or not at all).

To address the risk associated to *sales through Craigslist/Facebook*, Law Enforcement incentivates that these transactions be performed at [police station parking lots](http://www.marysvilleglobe.com/life/police-parking-lot-safe-place-for-internet-purchase-exchanges/) and other places classified as "safe zones". This initiative makes sense because officers would be nearby and the place is videotaped in case a situation degenerates.

Comment: The store isn't responsible for hiring security or any of that. If you destroy stuff they would call the police.

Comment: @Putvi I did not say or insinuate that the store is "*responsible for hiring security or any of that*". I said that the mere act of keeping the store out of the loop deprives it of the opportunity to assess and/or take whatever precautions it deems fit.

Comment: I understand that, but even if you did put the store in the loop they are gonna do the same thing.

Comment: @Putvi "*even if you did put the store in the loop they are gonna do the same thing*" ... with the difference that losses can be greater for the reason that it would take longer for the police or security to reach the place if they are not proactively given a headsup.

Comment: If you destroy it you will reimburse them.

Comment: @Putvi Right, but good luck if the disorderly person is broke and the store pursues *joint-and-several liability*.

Comment: That is not how criminal law works. If he commits a crime he is responsible.

Comment: @Putvi I am not talking about criminal law, but about the liability the other (non-disorderly) party might incur *with respect to the store*.

Comment: The process that would take place is criminal though. The disorderly party would get arrested and that is that.

Comment: @Putvi The important take-away from this is that a business would rather you not perform transactions on their property because they are not in the business of protecting random buyers and sellers. Just because they don't notice does not mean they are okay with you being there. It's akin to saying that drug deals often go unnoticed so the store is fine with the transaction taking place on their property. This answer adequately addresses the basis of my question.